# Case selection in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Here is my code:

```
  case input
  when "quit" || "exit"
    break
  end
```

Only "quit" works here and not "exit".

How could I have "exit" work too without having to have a new "when" line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
case input
when "quit", "exit"
  break
end
```

Comment: To explain why the original wasn't working: The `||` operator returns the first "truthy" operand. For example, the expression `1 || 2` returns 1, while `nil || 2` returns 2. So the expression `"quit" || "exit"` is equivalent to just `"quit"`.

Answer (score 0):

`||`operator evaluates the latter when the former is nil. `"quit"` is not nil. So `"quit" || "exit"` is `"quit"`.